# How to bind WPF if the containing element has properties of the same name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls

I have the following user control XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfEditorTest.PipelineView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfEditorTest"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Processors}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:EditorWindow WindowResize="EditorWindow_WindowResize">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Label Content="{Binding X}"/>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Y}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </local:EditorWindow>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
</UserControl>
```

DataContext of the usercontrol (set in constructor):

```
DataContext = new Pipeline("Pipeline1")
{
    Processors = 
    {
        new Processor("Add1"),
        new Processor("Add2"),
    }
};
```

Minimal versions of used (view)models:

```
public class Pipeline : Processor
{
    private ObservableCollection<Processor> m_Processors = new ObservableCollection<Processor>();

    public ObservableCollection<Processor> Processors
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Processors;
        }
    }
    public Pipeline(string name) : base(name)
    {
    }
}

public class Processor : NotifierBase
{
    private string m_Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return m_Name; }
        set { m_Name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }
    private double m_X;
    public double X
    {
        get { return m_X; }
        set { m_X = value; OnPropertyChanged("X"); }
    }
    private double m_Y;
    public double Y
    {
        get { return m_Y; }
        set { m_Y = value; OnPropertyChanged("Y"); }
    }
    public Processor(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public abstract class NotifierBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged Members
}
```

In this case, my DataContext (of the usercontrol itself) is an object with an ObservableCollection<> Processors, each processor has a Name, X and Y property. The EditorWindow also has a Name, X and Y property. How do i make it so the labels in the stackpanel show the value's of the DataContext of the usercontrol.

Result:

[image: Result of code]

Where it says 'EditorWindowControl' it should say 'Add1' or 'Add2', the current text is the Name property of the EditorWindow instance, not from the current item in the datacontext (processor) collection

Thank you for reading my question

**Edit:**

I changed the propertyname from Name to ProcessorName, and set the bind to "{Binding ProcessorName}" but now the binding fails (label is empty). So this means the way it binds is wrong, but I still don't know where it goes wrong.

Comment: This binding should show value of `DataContext` and not `EditorWindow`. I am only guessing but I think you're also setting `DataContext` of `EditorWindow` (in constructor) as you do for `PipelineView` hence you overwrite `DataContext`

Comment: @KingKing the {...} edits the already initialized version of Processors, the collection is initialized when the constructor gets called, the {...} will set the content of the collection, not (replace) the collection object itself.

Comment: well never tried such kind of initialization.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was in the `EditorWindow` control, in the constructor it sets the `DataContext` to itself, which overrides all other bindings from there on (apparently). After removing it the databinding worked.

Thanks to @dkozl for pointing this out

Comment: If you don't explicitly set binding context either by `ElementName`, `Source` or `RelativeSource` it will be `DataContext`. But each control can have only one `DataContext` value either inherited through visual tree (default) or manually set. It does not matter that `EditorWindow` and `Pipeline` have same property names because they are two different objects and two different binding sources